# API for Google Image Search

Tags: google-image-search

I'm wondering is there a method to use "search by image" from, for example, Java code? 
As a user I can open https://images.google.com/, click the little camera picture and upload an image. So there is the question, can I do it programmatically? I need just a link to the results. Thanks

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?  Looks like a perfectly reasonable thing to ask

Comment: Thank you! Since I can't find anything, I think it's a problem

Answer (score 0):

Selenium Webdriver is the word for it.

http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/